# How do I stop the animation player playing a timeline when I press the spacebar?

Tags: animation, timeline

When I press the spacebar in *Object* or *Edit Mode* the animation player starts playing a timeline, how do I stop this?

I checked the preferences and even set my spacebar hot key to activate my 3D cursor but the problem keeps coming back. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should be able to set the action for the space bar near the top of the Preferences > Keymap tab. From memory (don't have Blender running ATM), the options are Animation, Tools or Search. Save the settings if automatically save settings isn't checked.

Comment: @JohnEason Not bad.  You want "Frames" rather than "Animation" in recent Blender versions.  There are two entries for "Play Animation".  Just edit the first one (that's currently set to spacebar) and select any other key -- or you can delete the entry altogether.

Comment: @MartyFouts Well it was around 1am here when I posted that so I'll let myself off this time! :^)  I was actually talking about the 'Spacebar Action' setting under Preferences right at the top of the Keymap settings tab which is actually 'Play', 'Tools' or 'Search' so I wasn't that far out! I think that's an option on the original splash screen when you install Blender from new along with the Left/Right-Click select option?

Comment: @JohnEason I meant that as a compliment but even more so if it was 1am.  I had to look in Preferences to make sure and it was around 6pm so I have no excuse ;)